# uibarbutton item not showing uibutton

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

i saw many posts in SO on uibutton in navigation controller and on uibutton not working but my problem is uibutton is appearing in view intead on navigation controller here is my code

```
showMeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
showMeButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 100, 40);
[showMeButton setTitle:@"User Avtar" 
              forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[showMeButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:showMeButton];
[showMeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showMeButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

why this line of code not working `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:showMeButton];`

please help me out... thanks in advance :):)

Answer (score 1):

```
    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(00,15,50,26)];
    [button1 setTitle:@"User Avtar" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:button1];
```

Comment: even this doesnt work... button one doesnt appear neither in view nor in navigation controller

Comment: but it is not working for me @manish .. r u using another vc? i have this uibtn in view did load...

Comment: both in the ur code and one i tried button is in view not commin on navigation controller.. any idea y?

Comment: ok got it ... this can be done only in root view controller.. anyway thanks @manish :):)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
UINavigationItem *item = [navigationBar.items lastObject];
```

Now set your created barbuttonItem to the item's rightBarButtonItem,

```
item.rightBarButtonItem = button;
```

It's works for me.